# CSS multiple backgrounds issue

Tags: css

Why is this not working? How should I change it?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqsgck60/2/)

```
<div id="slider" class="middle">
</div>
#slider{
height:467px;
background:#eeeeee url(cercuri.png) no-repeat left top, url(cercuri2.png) no-repeat right top;
}
```

As you can see, I want a background-color and two images, one to the left and one to the right.

Comment: We don't have access to your *localhost*. What do you exactly mean by `not working`?

Comment: @HashemQolami I updated my jsfiddle. It is not displying the backgrounds. If I remove the second image, then it is working, but just with the color and one image.

Comment: So, the issue is that I make a mistake writting the second background image, but don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the color and leave it like this (sorry, I used my own images since you had your images at localhost)

```
#slider{
height:467px;
background-color:#eee;
background: url(http://c.dryicons.com/files/graphics_previews/sunset_landscape.jpg) no-repeat left top,  url(http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/e4/f8/e6/another-view-of-landscape.jpg) no-repeat right top;

}
```

you can see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bjk6Lgt/)

Comment: @Claudiu You should consider mark it an the answer.

Comment: really, if this is what you wanted and it was the 1st answer you can accept it

Answer (score 2):

Put the bg color ins the second call:

```
#slider{
    height:467px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) no-repeat left top, #eee url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) no-repeat right top ;
}
```

Comment: ok, from what I see it is working if I put the bg color in the second or third call. I really don't understand why it's not working on first call.. thanks!

Comment: It's documented: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background says "Note that a color is permitted in <final-bg-layer>, but not in <bg-layer>."

That also makes sense if you think of the layers: the last is the bottom one - otherwise your color would overwrite all other layers after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#slider{
    height:467px;    
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'), 
                url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
    background-position: left top, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slider" class="middle">
    <div id="slider1" style="float:left;width:50%;display:inline-block"></div>
    <div id="slider2" style="float:left;width:50%;display:inline-block"></div>
</div>

#slider{
    height:467px;
}
#slider1{
    height:467px;
background:#eeeeee url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-style-emoticons/256/Study-icon.png) no-repeat left top
}
#slider2{
 background:#eeeeee  url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png) no-repeat right top;   
height:467px;
}
```